# excel VBA: move overlapping shapes on worksheet

Tags: excel, object, textbox, vba

I am creating a calendar where it pulls events from a user inputsheet and places a text box object on another worksheet (Dates across the top and different departments down the left).  It currently seperates the events on the top row of each section (i.e. all HR events on top row of HR section).  I then run a MACRO to check for overlapping objects and move them down to the next row.

The code I use to move objects is below:

```
Sub MoveShapes()

'This Macro moves overlapping shapes down to the next row

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim s1 As Shape
Dim s2 As Shape
Dim CheckOverlap As Boolean

Worksheets("SRTC").Activate

    For i = 1 To sh.Shapes.count
        If i <= sh.Shapes.count Then
            Set s1 = sh.Shapes(i)
Search:
        CheckOverlap = False
            For Each s2 In Worksheets("SRTC").Shapes
                If s2.ID = s1.ID Then GoTo Suit
                If s2.Left <= (s1.Left + s1.Width) And s2.Left >= s1.Left _
                And s2.Top <= (s1.Top + s1.Height) And s2.Top >= s1.Top Then
                    s1.Top = s1.Top + 18 ' 32
                CheckOverlap = True
            Exit For
            End If
Suit:
            Next
        If CheckOverlap = True Then GoTo Search
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

(I found this code in a different forum) This code works but is extremely slow.  It is comparing each textbox with all the text boxes on the worksheet.  My worksheet has over 3000 shapes and the MACRO takes over 4 hours to run.

Is there a way to write this code to only move objects within certain ranges? (ie only HR section)

Thanks

Comment: Wow, 3000 shapes sounds excessive. I'm sure there must be a better approach. That said you can check for an `Intersect` using the e.g. `Topleftcell` property of a shape.

Comment: It is alot of shapes.  Currently I thinned it down to about 1400 but I am expecting a lot of more (2000 +) inputs shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be to use `application.screenupdating`.

Also some variable declarations are not or badly done (i, Sh).

Don't use `Goto`. (i may use a `do while` or `do until` loop)

Why test on each loop  `If i <= sh.Shapes.count Then`wich obviously is the case?

You can avoid `If s2.ID = s1.ID Then GoTo Suit` by not using a for each (wich tests shapes already corrected also), but `for j=i+ 1 to sh.shapes.count : set S2=sh.shapes(j)` ....`

little reminder : on long IF tests , with several conditions, VBA will test all the conditions before continuing, so instead of testing 4 conditions, test only the 2 more important and `then` test the two others, for example.

Beware, comments, buttons, and many other stuff is also a shape, so you might need a test of the shape's type (on s1). Avoid unessaceray looping.

On a personal note, i'd use a dictionary and a class type, the whole thing would take max 5 secondes to loop, and no i won't write that code for you.
Your approach is more at your level and is good enough with a bit of code optimization using the hints i gave.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will attempt to incorporate your ideas to speed up my macro.  I do have the screenupdating set to false on my main macro which calls this macro. However, I am not familiar with either using dictionary or class type.  Those might be above my skill level at this time.  Thanks again for the response.